# Lodash orderBy - sort price with $ sign at start like numbers

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects:

```
[{id:1, name:"Samsung", price :"$937.78", rating :4.5}, ..]
```

When I sort by price it sort it as a string. I tried to splice $ sign but it doesn't work - it sorts as a string.

```
orderBy(this.props.price_list, item =>  item.price.slice(1), [sortDir.toLowerCase()])
```

**P.S.** 
Sorry to all, I didn't noticed that `if statement` wasn't correct, so I was sorting array two times, 1st as a number and  2nd as a string

```
  sortTable(sortDir = 'ASC', columnName) {

    if (columnName === 'price'){
      this.setState({ list: orderBy(this.props.price_list, item =>  parseFloat(item.price.slice(1)), [sortDir.toLowerCase()]) })
    }
    this.setState({ list: orderBy(this.props.price_list, [columnName], [sortDir.toLowerCase()]) })
  }
```

Comment: It's still a string after the slice. Put a plus before the item.price.slice(1): `+item.price.slice(1)`.

Comment: you will get price in any other currency? because it looks like working https://codepen.io/kejt/pen/RgOqXY?editors=1111

Comment: what about prices 100 and 97? it's not working

Comment: @gruff-bunny  +  and parsefloat are not helpful

Comment: Show some more data as it would help to give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parseFloat` on the string

```
orderBy(this.props.price_list, item =>  parseFloat(item.price.slice(1)), [sortDir.toLowerCase()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `regex` to compare number values only.

```js
let arr = [{id:1, name:"Samsung", price :"$937.78", rating :4.5},
  {id:2, name:"Samsung", price :"$37.78", rating :4.5},
  {id:3, name:"Samsung", price :"$222.78", rating :4.5},
];

arr.sort((a,b) => a.price.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0] - b.price.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0]);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `parseFloat()` -> item.price.substring(1):

```js
let arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Samsung",
  price: "$937.78",
  rating: 4.5
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "Samsung1",
  price: "$97.78",
  rating: 4.5
}];
arr.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price.substring(1)) - parseFloat(b.price.substring(1)));
console.log(arr);
```